# How can I force use generator on Coffeescript 1.9?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, generator, ecmascript-6, koa

CoffeeScript support generator now, but, I found only you use `yield` keyword, then your function will be compiled to generator, here is my question, I use `koa` to write my code, and some middleware I do not need async logic, so I don't need `yield`, so, CoffeeScript think it is an normal function, but, `koa` says: `app.use() requires a generator function`, T^T, anyone have a solution? Thank You!

Comment: Is not using Coffeescript a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the force, Luke! ;)

I ported the [example from the homepage](http://koajs.com/#cascading) to CoffeeScript, and simply made the last handler also accept a `next` argument and `yield` to it, despite that being totally unnecessary.

Turns it works just fine. Doing `yield null` instead, however, does not work.

```
koa = require("koa")
app = koa()

# x-response-time

app.use (next) ->
  start = new Date
  yield next
  ms = new Date - start
  @set 'X-Response-Time', ms + 'ms'

# logger

app.use (next) ->
  start = new Date
  yield next
  ms = new Date - start
  console.log '%s %s - %s', this.method, this.url, ms

# response

app.use (next) ->
  @body = "Hello World"
  yield next

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: I tried about it, it worked, but I thought it was unnecessary, and if someone  read this code, it'll confused about it, thought there is another middleware after this. Is official offer an solution? I try to find out some other ways, but I failed.

Comment: No, as far as I know there is no explicit way to make a generator in CoffeeScript, only `yield` will do it.

Comment: However, if you definitely don't want any other middlewares to run after this one, you could try `yield ->` (i.e. yield to an empty function).

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this coffeescript issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3823), you can use `yield return` to force the function to be a generator.
I know it's not pretty, but it seems to be the only option at this point.